# How to update a look up column using a grid?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have an Employee list which has 2 columns(department and manager) which are lookup columns. I need code to update these lookup columns when a new user registers. (Though the other columns are being updated in the list)

The following is the code:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://sp13appstoredev.xyz.com/sites/DevApps/TrainingSite/"))
        {
            clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
            List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Employees");
            clientContext.Load(oList);
            ListItemCreationInformation itemInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem myItem = oList.AddItem(itemInfo);
            myItem["Title"] = txtFirstName.Text;
            myItem["Last_x0020_Name"] = txtLastName.Text;
            myItem["u5ib"] = txtAge.Text;
            myItem["Address"] = txtAddress.Text;
            //FieldLookupValue lookUpDepartment = new FieldLookupValue();
            //myItem["Department"] = lookUpDepartment as FieldLookupValue;
            //FieldLookupValue lookUpManager = new FieldLookupValue();
            //myItem["Manager"] = lookUpManager as FieldLookupValue;
            myItem["Gender"] = radioBtnGender.Text;
            myItem["Salary"] = txtSalary.Text;
            myItem.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

I commented the lookup column lines to check if the other columns are being updated in the list.
Kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me :

```
myItem["Department"] = 1;

myItem["Manager"] = 1;
```

I also had to change the parent list to ID (which was earlier Title)

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://sp13appstoredev.xyz.com/sites/DevApps/TrainingSite/"))
{
    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
    List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Employees");
    clientContext.Load(oList);
    ListItemCreationInformation itemInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem myItem = oList.AddItem(itemInfo);
    myItem["Title"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    myItem["Last_x0020_Name"] = txtLastName.Text;
    myItem["u5ib"] = txtAge.Text;
    myItem["Address"] = txtAddress.Text;
    var lookUpDepartment = new FieldLookupValue{LookupId = departmentId};
    myItem["Department"] = lookUpDepartment;
    var lookUpManager = new FieldLookupValue{LookupId = managerId};
    myItem["Manager"] = lookUpManager;
    myItem["Gender"] = radioBtnGender.Text;
    myItem["Salary"] = txtSalary.Text;
    myItem.Update();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Examples [here](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/setting-the-value-of-a-lookup-field-using-csom/) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/96a20ee3-adfd-473c-b1bf-c1e22f22242e/getset-value-for-lookup-field-using-client-object-model-sharepoint-2013?forum=appsforsharepoint).

Comment: The following line gives error because of the departmentId, I need to update the lookup column by value and not by ID. var lookUpDepartment = new FieldLookupValue{LookupId = departmentId}; @wjervis

Comment: @SanjanaV You might be able to use LookupValue instead of LookupId, but I am not sure if that will work.